# How can I add a breakpoint to debug my R package without recompiling

Tags: r, r-package

When I develop a R package I endup doing the following thing:

1. load the latest build
2. use it
3. realize there is a bug in say function 'f_bug'
4. try to debug

I would be easy if I could just 're-source' `f_bug` and that the newly sourced version would be chosen (I'd rebuild the package clean latter).

But I cannot do that, it looks like the `package::f_bug` is always "chosen" by default when called within another package function.

Can I do such a thing ?

Comment: After rebuild it have you tried to load it again?!

Comment: That's the whole point I do not want to have to rebuild it each time I want to put a breakpoint !

Comment: Maybe from the command line: `trace(package::f_bug, browser, at = line_you_want_to_insert_breakpoint_at)`

Comment: ah ! I'll try that looks good

Answer (score 2):

You can't use RStudio's convenient graphical breakpoints, but you can do the same thing using `trace`:

```
trace(package::f_bug, browser, at = insertion_point)
```

Here `insertion_point` refers not to line numbers but to a vector of substeps. From `?trace`:

> look at ‘as.list(body(f))’ to get the numbers
>       associated with the steps in function ‘f’.)

Another option might be to use `utils::setBreakpoint` which takes a file name and line number as arguments. See the help file for details.

Comment: Can you trace only once ?

Comment: `trace` stays on until you use `untrace`, I don't think there is an equivalent to `debugonce`.